# Load average 1.00 while top seems to show the server as idle

Tags: top, high-load, uptime

My server is not responding to HTTP requests, and it took me a long time before being able to log in with SSH; it all looks like the server is overloaded and on its knees.

It already did that a few days ago, but after a reboot everything was back to normal. Today before rebooting, I'd like to understand what's happening.

I've finally been able to log in, and the load average shows a steady `1.00`:

```
# uptime
15:00:46 up 4 days, 19:47,  1 user,  load average: 1.00, 1.00, 1.00
```

But `top` seems to say that the server is idle:

```
top - 15:01:52 up 4 days, 19:48,  1 user,  load average: 1.00, 1.00, 1.00
Tasks: 704 total,   1 running, 703 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
Cpu(s):  0.3%us,  1.1%sy,  0.0%ni, 98.4%id,  0.0%wa,  0.0%hi,  0.2%si,  0.0%st
Mem:   4034032k total,  4009704k used,    24328k free,    16612k buffers
Swap:  1959920k total,    58576k used,  1901344k free,    22860k cached

  PID USER      PR  NI  VIRT  RES  SHR S %CPU %MEM    TIME+  COMMAND
19137 root      16   0 13152 1748  936 R  2.9  0.0   0:00.27 top
    1 root      15   0 10364  744  620 S  0.0  0.0   0:03.26 init
    2 root      RT  -5     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.02 migration/0
    3 root      34  19     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.65 ksoftirqd/0
    4 root      RT  -5     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 watchdog/0
    5 root      RT  -5     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 migration/1
    6 root      34  19     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.21 ksoftirqd/1
    7 root      RT  -5     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 watchdog/1
    8 root      10  -5     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:04.73 events/0
    9 root      10  -5     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:02.29 events/1
   10 root      10  -5     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.01 khelper
   47 root      20  -5     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 kthread
   52 root      10  -5     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.02 kblockd/0
   53 root      10  -5     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.05 kblockd/1
   54 root      15  -5     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 kacpid
  165 root      11  -5     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 cqueue/0
  166 root      11  -5     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 cqueue/1
```

Oh, and I've also seen the following messages in httpd's `error_log`:

> PHP Fatal error:  SQLSTATE[08004] [1040] Too many connections in ...

But `access_log` shows no requests for the last 8 hours, as all HTTP connections end up in a timeout...

Does anyone have an explanation for that?

Comment: Hard drive perhaps? Take a look at your smart attributes and maybe `iotop`.

Comment: Also, you have 700+ processes. Have a look at `ps aux` to see what's running.

Comment: What OS is it? How many CPUs?

Comment: The hard drive was simply full, I should have checked this first. Problem solved, thanks guys for your comments!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `/var` partition was simply full, hence the SQL errors as this is the partition where the mysql data is stored.

The main reason was that binary logging was enabled even though I wasn't using it for replication or anything, so I disabled this, removed the binary logs, and everything is back to normal!